# I decided not to ____

Tags: ellipsis, to-infinitive

> A: Did you play tennis last weekend? 
> B: No, I wasn't feeling so well, so I decided not to _____.

What CAN'T you say in the blank?
a. (nothing) 
b. do
c. do so
d. do it
e. do that
f. play
g. play tennis
h. play tennis last weekend

---

Why do I ask this question?
Because I know that you can end the sentence with "to" as in (a). And I also know that you can add "do so/it/that" after "to". And I also know that you can repeat the verb phrase with or without "last weekend".

But I can't find a rule that you can omit the object and just use "play" as in (f), although somehow (f) does sound fine to my ears.

When can we end the sentence with a lexical verb (e.g., *play*) and omit its object (e.g., *tennis*)?

Could someone find me some authoritative source on this particular point?

Comment: You missed out (h) *...so I decided not to **play tennis last weekend***, which is the "complete" version.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. It's been incorporated now.

Answer (score 2):

If you put **(b) "do"** in the blank, the sentence would be incomplete.

> *I wasn't feeling so well, so I decided not to *do*.

The other versions would be all correct, even **(f)** which omits the direct object because it is so obvious.

Comment: I agree with you, but it doesn't explain why b) doesn't work. The sentence isn't complete with a) either, but that's quite acceptable. Actually I think b) is possible, but only with _do_ unstressed - in which case you might as well say a). The others all have at least some stress on _do_ or _play_.

Comment: Please note the question has been edited.